# Where is the Avengers/Stark tower located?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, avengers-age-of-ultron

In Age of Ultron, Tony Stark's office building / home/ Avengers HQ is a high rise building in Manhattan.  It is seen with Grand Central Station in the foreground in north-facing views, so it must be a small number of blocks north of Grand Central Station.  It is also possible to see the Chrysler building from Stark/Avengers Tower, so it is probably east of the Chrysler building, somewhere in midtown.  But where in specific is the Avengers/Stark tower located?

Has anyone seen an actual address description?  And I am curious, what other building is actually in the same location in real life?

Answer (score 2):

200 Park Avenue, New York, NY, 10166 in the MCU

[Marvel Wiki](http://marvel.wikia.com/Stark_Tower)